# Eclipse: Is this possible to run FindBugs on file save action?

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I am using Eclipse indigo 3.7.2.  I am using  FindBugs to detect issues. Every time I did any modification in a class I need to rerun the report to check the issues. Is there any way to run the `FindBugs` on file save action?

Comment: it might get rather annoying ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to see the FindBugs results in Eclipse right click your project `Properties` -> `FindBugs` -> `Enable project specific settings` -> `Run automatically`.

Comment: Works fine for me in Luna (4.4.1)